# jQuery Ajax return value not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

The function rk() returns random key from an Ajax call, parameter l stands for length. My question is how can I take the return value from the Ajax result in my "k" variable?

```
var k = rk(6);

function rk(l) { //l stands for length
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax_lib.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : 'k=1&l=' + l,
        success : function(r) {
            return r;
        }                     
    });            
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ajax uses asynchronous processing, means once the request is sent to the server, it will keep executing the remaining statements without waiting for the response.

So in your case once the request is sent to the server, `rk` returns `undefined`(since there is no return statement) value the variable `k` will have value `undefined`.

To solve this problem make use of the [promise](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise) object returned by $.ajax

```
rk(6).done(function(r){
    //do what ever you want to do with r
});

function rk(l) {  //l stands for lenght           

    return $.ajax({                  
        url : 'ajax_lib.php',                 
        type : 'POST',                
        data : 'k=1&l=' + l                 
    });  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be

```
function rk(myVariable, l) {  //l stands for lenght           

    $.ajax({                  
        url : 'ajax_lib.php',                 
        type : 'POST',                
        data : 'k=1&l=' + l,              
        success : function(r)    {               
            myVariable = r;
        }                                   
    });  

}
```

and instead of calling `r=rk(l)`
you can call `rk(r, l)`